# Is there a command for large middle delimiters consistent with \bigl and \bigr?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

After browsing through related threads, I am now of the understanding (please correct me if I am wrong) that the rule of thumb is to use the `\bigl`,`\bigr` pair with brackets, parentheses, etc. for operators like sums, products, and integrals, and `\left`,`\right` in all other cases.

I only recently found out about `\middle` , which has solved what had been a vexing problem for me: delimiters for function arguments (slashes, bars) not scaling properly. Leafing through my cheatsheet has not been of much help, so I wish to ask: is there an equivalent of `\middle` for `\bigl` and `\bigr`, or would the use of `\middle` along with that pair not be gauche?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

\bigm, \Bigm, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Also, if you need the large middle delimiters for typing set-builder or bra-ket notation, you can use the `\Set{...|...}`, `\Braket{...|...}`, `\Bra{...}`, and `\Ket{...}` commands from the braket package.