# Continued Fractions as an operator.

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

In dealing with continued fractions in LaTeX, I've become less and less enamored of the `\cfrac` construct. Especially in my case where I deal with complicated numerators and denominators, listing a few terms can get unwieldy.

I encountered a nice notation for CFs in Lorentzen and Waadeland's "Continued Fractions with Applications" that seemed to be adaptable to my needs. I have no digital copy of the book, so I offer Wolfram's approximation on how this operator is rendered:

[image: continued fraction]

(the only difference is that the b terms come before the a terms, and they are separated by a backslash (this is why I asked this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/is-there-a-command-for-large-middle-delimiters-consistent-with-bigl-and-bigr), so I now know how to render the operands and the delimiters properly))

My question now, then, is how can I construct a "continued fraction operator" that acts like `\sum` and `\product`? Somehow, trying to use a large letter K and then putting the limits as over- and underscripts has been a bit of a mixed bag (and of course, if the operands themselves are fractions, I have to manually tweak the size of the "K" again!). Might there be a more elegant approach to this?

Comment: Wikipedia says the notation is due to Gauss.  Despite its distinguished origin, I don't like it: I have to consciously resist cancelling the fraction.  Better to add some sign to the fraction, say a trailing vertical slash on the denominator, to indicate this isn't a real fraction.

Comment: That's actually why I substitute a backslash for a slash in my set of notes, and then place b before a; at least for me it reinforces psychologically that this is not your "typical" fraction. I'm of course not entirely sure that my modification will catch on, but what can you do... :)

Answer (score 9):

I'd define a new operator:

```
\newcommand{\K}{\operatornamewithlimits{K}}
```

You can then do the following:

```
Math-mode example:
\[
        \K_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{b_k}
\]
or inline $\K_k \frac{a_k}{b_k}$.
```

And get:

[image]

(Note that you must `\usepackage{amsmath}`.)

Comment: The documentation for amsmath says `\operatorname*` gives this behavior but doesn't mention `\operatornamewithlimits` at all.  Is this an undocumented synonym?

Comment: You know, I'm not sure where I picked up this trick. I use it for `argmax` and `argmin`.

Comment: Egh, I guess I was unclear! I said the notation at Wolfram was just an approximation! (What I was trying to do looks something like K(b\a) with the appropriate over- and underscripts.) I think I can use this, however. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\raisebox{-5pt}{\huge K}}}
```

gives a fairly good result. Your example would be:

```
\[ \bigk_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{b_k} \]
```

Comment: To use your `\bigk`, the notation I would actually be using would be something like `\[ \bigk_{k=0}^\infty \bigl (b_k \bigm\backslash a_k \bigr ) \]` ; would this scale properly if, say, I replace the `a_k` and `b_k` with a `\frac` construct?

Comment: @J. Mangaldan: Do `\sum` and `\product` scale automatically? I don't see that they do?

Comment: I would use `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` rather than `\raisebox{-5pt}{...}`

Comment: Lev: Odd... I tried it out: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac{\ln(j+1)}{j!}}{\binom{n}{j}} just now... I suppose my memory was mistaken. So using that construct would make the K act like `\sum`, `\product`, and `\int`?