# How to format K notation for continued fractions

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, characters

Over [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.13597.pdf) is a recent paper on continued fractions, and I was wondering how I could format Gauss' K notation in this fashion. Here is a picture to demonstrate what I mean:

[image: K notation image]

I am unsure how to format the alligned position of the + signs and ellipsis without aligning them with the vinculums of the fractions `a(k)/b(k)`.

To format the size, font, indices, etc of the K notation, I tried doing: `\operatornamewithlimits{\Large{\Bigg\mathcal{K}}}}_{m=1}^\infty` 
 or 
 `\operatorname*{\Large{\Bigg\mathcal{K}}}}\limits_{m=1}^\infty` 
 and experimented with `\large`, `\big`, `\bigg`, with or without.

It seems that the size is right, but the indices are... way off. Can somebody help me, please? I have searched for some related posts (e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/continued-fractions-as-an-operator)), but amidst my search, I could not find the appropriate format I am looking for, as depicted above.

My thoughts: I think I need to install a package (e.g. amsmath) that can enhance typesetting and other facilities. I am writing a paper on Overleaf - does Overleaf come wit this package?

I am not new to TeX, but I believe this is either my first or second post. If I am doing something wrong, or failing to follow the guidelines, please let me know asap, and I will try to amend my question/post accordingly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you need the `amsmath` package to use `\operatornamewithlimits` or `\operatorname` regardless?

Comment: You can download the source at https://arxiv.org/format/1909.13597 and will find that the author uses https://gist.github.com/moewew/0141c642d3b2bf95dd8dcba1b537c6ee. I'm not sure if that's the "best solution", but it may be a start (I would certainly use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`). (To answer your question about Overleaf: Overleaf has all packages installed that come with a normal TeX live installation. `amsmath` is definitely one of those. You can just say `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble and are good to go.)

Comment: Very related (with a definition of `\contFracOpe` that looks familiar)  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73195/35864. Also interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/35864

Comment: For one the `\mathrm` in the code of `\contFracOpe` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Mr Pie, I have a feeling I'm missing something here because the answer you linked to seems fairly complex, but perhaps you could write `\DeclareMathOperator*{\Kay}{\vcenter{\hbox{\huge\(\mathcal{K}\)}}}` and `\newcommand{\bottom}[1]{\begin{array}{c}{}\\#1\end{array}}` in your preamble, and then in your document write `\[\Kay_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{a_m}{b_m}\bigg) :=\frac{a_1}{b_1}\bottom{+} \frac{a_2}{b_2} \bottom{+} \frac{a_3}{b_3} \bottom{+}\bottom{\cdots}\]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can download the source of the arXiv paper at https://arxiv.org/format/1909.13597 (choose [*Download source*](https://arxiv.org/e-print/1909.13597) to download the `.tex` file).

The paper uses

```
\def\contFracOpe{%
    \operatornamewithlimits{%
        \mathchoice{% * Display style
            \vcenter{\hbox{\huge $\mathcal{K}$}}%
        }{%           * Text style
            \vcenter{\hbox{\Large $\mathcal{K}$}}%
        }{%           * Script style
            \mathrm{\mathcal{K}}%
        }{%           * Script script style
            \mathrm{\mathcal{K}}%
        }
    }
}
```

That definition seems to come from [projetmbc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6880/projetmbc)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73229/35864) to [How to typeset a continued fraction in the following format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73195/35864) which in term refers to user2478's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23440/35864) to [How to create my own math operator with limits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/35864).

I usually prefer `\newcommand` over `\def` for commands in the preamble and the `\mathrm`'s are unnecessary, so I would probably make that definition read

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand\ContFracOp{%
  \operatornamewithlimits{%
    \mathchoice
     {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge $\mathcal{K}$}}}
     {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large $\mathcal{K}$}}}
     {\mathcal{K}}
     {\mathcal{K}}}}


\begin{document}
$\ContFracOp\dots\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k e^{\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k}$

\[\ContFracOp\dots\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k e^{\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: \ContFracOp with \mathchoice]

An alternative would be to base `\ContFracOp` on [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/35864) that makes use of `graphicx`'s `\resizebox` to scale the symbol to the same size as `\sum`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#1}{#2}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{\ifx#1\displaystyle#2\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#3$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\ContFracOp}{\DOTSB\bigop[.96]{\mathcal{K}}}

\begin{document}
$\ContFracOp\dots\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k e^{\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k}$

\[\ContFracOp\dots\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k e^{\ContFracOp_{k=1}^m x_k}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: \ContFracOp with scalebox]

I found the magic number `.96` in the optional argument to `\bigop` in the definition of `\ContFracOp` by trial and error. It helps manually correct the scaling of the symbol to match the height of `\sum` as closely as possible.

Comment: Wasn't sure which to answer to accept, thus I went for the most-voted. Congratulations! `$\Large\color{green}{\checkmark}$` :)

Answer (score 8):

A simplification of moewe's answer. As a bonus, also the alternative notation for continued fractions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gaussk}{\DOTSB\gaussk@\slimits@}
\newcommand{\gaussk@}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigcal@{K}}}

\newcommand{\bigcal@}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\m@th
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \dimen@=\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{0.8\dimen@}{$\mathcal{K}$}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\cfracplus}{\mathbin{\cfracplus@}}
\newcommand{\cfracplus@}{%
  \sbox\z@{$\dfrac{1}{1}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$+$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp\tw@-\dp\z@\relax}{$+$}%
}
\newcommand{\cfracdots}{\mathord{\cfracdots@}}
\newcommand{\cfracdots@}{%
  \sbox\z@{$\dfrac{1}{1}$}%
  \sbox\tw@{$+$}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\dp\tw@-\dp\z@\relax}{$\cdots$}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
e^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^k}{k!}+\frac{n^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\biggl(
1+n+\gaussk_{m=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{-n(m+n-1)}{m+2n-1}\Bigr)\biggr)
\]

\[
\gaussk_{m=1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{a_m}{b_m}\Bigr)=
\frac{a_1}{b_1}\cfracplus
\frac{a_2}{b_2}\cfracplus
\frac{a_3}{b_3}\cfracplus\cfracdots
\]

\[
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gaussk_{n=1}^\infty
\quad
\textstyle
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gaussk_{n=1}^\infty
\quad
\scriptstyle
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\gaussk_{n=1}^\infty
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An elementary solution, not as general, based on `\genfrac` and package `scalerel`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\newcommand{\cadd}[1][0pt]{\mathbin{\genfrac{}{}{#1}{0}{}{+}}}
\newcommand{\Cdots}[1][0pt]{\genfrac{}{}{#1}{0}{\mbox{}}{\cdots}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Kont}{\mathcal{K}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigKont}{\scalerel*{ \mathcal{K}}{\big(}}

\begin{document}
    \[\bigKont_{m = 1}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{a_m}{b_m}\Bigr)\coloneqq \frac{a_1}{b_1}\cadd \frac{a_2}{b_2}\cadd \frac{a_3}{b_3}\cadd\Cdots \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]